# Efficiently count frequency of n-grams at start of words

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms, strings, search-problem

I have a text file with all possible 5-grams (26^5 = 11.881.376) organized in rows as:

aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
aaaad
.....

and I have a txt file (organized in rows) with all English words. I have to find how much time every 5-gram is at the beginning of a word. I'm using this code:

```
def frequency(five-grams, dict):
    result = {}

    for gram in five-grams:
        freq = 0
        for word in dict:
            if word.startswith(gram): 
               freq = freq + 1

        result[gram] = freq

    return result
```

However this method takes too long (after hours the algorithm is still running). Is there a more efficient and faster method?

Comment: Sort and merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 11.881.376 times faster method. Instead of for every 5-gram looping over the entire dictionary, loop over the dictionary once, and for every word determine with what 5-gram it starts and then increment the counter for that particular 5-gram.

Comment: Note that this only helps if the 5-grams are stored in an appropriate data structure, like a hashmap. If you want to do this for n-grams of different n's at the same time, a trie is a good structure to go for.